# Running python script from crontab?

Tags: python, unix, cron

I need some help running a python script from crontab:

The script looks for subfolders from current path and does something to them, also extracts a zip file located in the same folder of the script into each found subfolder.

When I go with `cd /folder/folder` then `python script.py` is all good. But when run it with crontab it runs in users home folder and not where the script is placed.

To overcome this I placed in crontab something like this:

```
* * * * cd /folder_of_scrpit/ && /python_path/python script.py >> log.txt
```

and works as needed but feels weird, is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `cd` in crontab the way you do it. Or you can call `os.chdir()` in your script. In the latter case you can write the directory in the script or pass it as a command line argument: `/python path/python script.py /folder/folder`.

Comment: When using cd in crontab it feels un-natural or hardcoded that's why i'm trying to find a better way.

Comment: In my opinion it's more natural. But it's pure opinionated. :-)

Comment: Oh, I've forgotten to include 2 more variants: read the directory from an environment variable or from a config file. I'm sure you could invent such methods yourself. And I still think that for a simple case `cd` in the shell/cron is the simplest and cleanest way. Good luck!